# Compute two proportion tests (with three variables?)

Tags: r, validation

I want to make sure I'm running these proportion tests correctly to show that there are differences in outcomes for three groups. I am working off [of this guide](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/two-proportions-z-test-in-r#r-functions-prop.test), except I have an additional group. Does the proportional test from this code work?:

```
crosstab(hcad_acs$type_flag, (hcad_acs$distance < 50), plot=FALSE, prop.r=TRUE)
   Cell Contents 
|-------------------------|
|                   Count | 
|             Row Percent | 
|-------------------------|

===========================================
                      (hcad_acs$distance < 50)
hcad_acs$type_flag    FALSE    TRUE   Total
-------------------------------------------
buyout                  75     215     290 
                      25.9%   74.1%   11.6%
-------------------------------------------
prox                   557    1161    1718 
                      32.4%   67.6%   68.6%
-------------------------------------------
safe                   204     291     495 
                      41.2%   58.8%   19.8%
-------------------------------------------
Total                  836    1667    2503 
===========================================

prop.test(x=c(215, 1161, 291), n = c(290, 1718, 495), p = NULL, alternative = "two.sided",
+           correct = TRUE)

    3-sample test for equality of proportions without continuity correction

data:  c(215, 1161, 291) out of c(290, 1718, 495)
X-squared = 22, df = 2, p-value = 0.00002
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
prop 1 prop 2 prop 3 
 0.741  0.676  0.588
```

Comment: The manual page for `prop.test` states "If p is NULL and there is more than one group, the null tested is that the proportions in each group are the same. ... The alternative is always "two.sided", the returned confidence interval is NULL, and continuity correction is never used."  Are you looking for anything more than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comment.**  One more thing: In R, the procedure `prop.test` is
essentially the same as a chi-squared test of homogeneity, using your $3 \times 2$ table. Except for rounding, the
chi-squared statistic, DF, and P-value are the same, so
that the null hypothesis of equal proportions is rejected.

```
B = c(75, 215);  P = c(557, 1161);  S = c(204,291)
TBL = rbind(B,P,S);  TBL
  [,1] [,2]
B   75  215
P  557 1161
S  204  291
chisq.test(TBL)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL
X-squared = 21.728, df = 2, p-value = 1.913e-05
```

Depending on objectives, either format can be more
convenient.

In the chi-squared test, one can look at Pearson
residuals. The sum of their squares is the chi-squared
statistic. So, looking for residuals largest in
absolute value provides a guide as to the cells
of the table in which departure from homogeneity
is most extreme.

```
chisq.test(TBL)$resi
        [,1]       [,2]
B -2.2211293  1.5729292
P -0.7017778  0.4969755
S  3.0074838 -2.1297991
```

Here, it might be worthwhile to compare
the first and last row:

```
TBL[c(1,3),]
  [,1] [,2]
B   75  215
S  204  291
```

Using `cor=F` to decline the Yates continuity correction
for moderately large counts.

```
chisq.test(TBL[c(1,3),], cor=F)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL[c(1, 3), ]
X-squared = 18.808, df = 1, p-value = 1.446e-05
```

Notes: (a) If several such *ad hoc* tests are done in a larger
table, you should use some method (such as Bonferroni) to
avoid false discovery from repeated analyses on the same data.

(b) In case some of the cells of the table have very low
counts, you may get a warning message that the P-value of the chi-squared test may not
be correct. Then you can use parameter `sim=T` to
simulate a more useful P-value. Illustration for
a table with sparse counts:

```
TBL.s = rbind(c(2,3, 30), c(5,5,10))
TBL.s
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    3   30
[2,]    5    5   10
```

Warning message:

```
chisq.test(TBL.s)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  TBL.s
X-squared = 8.3131, df = 2, p-value = 0.01566

Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL.s) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Warning triggered because some expected counts
are below $5.$

```
chisq.test(TBL.s)$exp
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 4.454545 5.090909 25.45455
[2,] 2.545455 2.909091 14.54545
Warning message:
In chisq.test(TBL.s) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Simulation shows significance at 2% level.

```
chisq.test(TBL.s, sim=T)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test 
        with simulated p-value 
        (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  TBL.s
X-squared = 8.3131, df = NA, p-value = 0.01949
```